# Assigning Strings to field of Partially Filled Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a text file that contains about 80000+ words. I'm trying to check the length of these words and see if it matches a number entered without using an Array Lists.

Say that an array has these global variables:

```
public static int INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
public static int size;
public String[] array = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];
```

I'm going to create an object:

```
PartArray part = new PartArray();
```

And a field:

```
part.array = new String[INITIAL_SIZE];
```

(And then proceed to expand the array with another method by multiplying the initial size by 2 until it can contain all 80000+ words)

But I want to assign every word in the array at 0, 1, 2, ..... (80000 -1) to something of the extent;

```
part.array[part.size++] = "aardvark";
.....
part.array[part.size++] = "zymurgy";
```

so that I can print the words that have this specific length.

```
part.array[0];
```

But how would I do that? Should I create another class in java? I just don't want to put "String" in front of every word in that text file.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ArrayList?

Comment: @JimN I'm trying to understand this fundamentally, is it possible without an ArrayList?

Comment: It sounds to me that what you are describing is an implementation of ArrayList.  So you could implement your own (using arrays internally), or you could use the existing ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure if I understood what you were trying to do, but from what I understand, you want to implement something similar to an ArrayList..

First let's clarify something. The code example you posted will always result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
part.array[part.size++] = "aardvark";
.....
part.array[part.size++] = "zymurgy";
```

No matter how big your array is, you'll try to access memory, which is outside of that array.
If you really do not want to use an ArrayList (or any other List), you might want to create your own class which behaves in a similar way..

```
public class StringList{
    public static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_SIZE = 100;
    public static final float DEFAULT_SCALE_FACTOR = 2;

    private String[] content;
    private float scaleFactor;
    private int counter = 0;

    public StringList(){
        this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_SIZE);
    }

    public StringList(int initialSize){
        this(initialSize, DEFAULT_SCALE_FACTOR);
    }

    public StringList(int initialSize, float scaleFactor){
        this.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        content = new String[initialSize];
    }

    public void add(String toAdd){
        //check if we ran out of space for new content..
        if(counter == content.length){
            //create a new array with twice the current arrays size
            String[] temp = new String[(int) (content.length * scaleFactor)];
            //efficiently copy content from current array to temp
            System.arraycopy(content, 0, temp, 0, content.length);
            content = temp;
        }
        content[counter++] = toAdd;
    }

    public String get(int index){
        return content[index];
    }

    public int size(){
        return counter;
    }
}
```

That class should do everything you need..
Here a short example..

```
StringList stringList = new StringList();
stringList.add("aardvark");
// add more stuff...
stringList.add("zymurgy");

for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    String someText = stringList.get(i);
    // do stuff with your string...
}
```

Comment: You could do it with generics, like the ArrayList does, but I think that was not what you wanted to do.. It would also be nice, if it implemented the List<T> or the Iterable<String> Interface, but we don't want things to get messy, do we? :)